# uClibc shared libs unloading during exit()

Tags: linux, multithreading, shared-libraries, libc, uclibc

I'm using a shared library that creates worker threads during initialization. The app is linked with uClibc. When it returns from main() it crashes in `__pthread_cond_wait()` or similar from a worker thread that the shared lib doesn't properly stop from its cleanup() code. The main() thread stack when it crashes is:

```
#0 _dl_munmap from uClibc.so
#1 _dl_fini 
#2 __GI_exit 
#3 __uClibc_main
```

Since I don't have source for the shared library I can't fix the worker cleanup code, but my question is:

Why are threads still running (crashing) once uClibc starts unloading shared libs ? I assume it's unloading them from the `_dl_munmap` stack entry above. Is there a way to make sure all threads are paused/stopped when main() exits ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why are threads still running

Because *you* (or the shared library you link against) left them running.

> Is there a way to make sure all threads are paused/stopped when main() exits

Yes: *you* need to arrange for threads to terminate. Without access to the shared library source, you can't really do that; your only other choice is to call `_exit` (which should not run any cleanup) instead of `exit` (or instead of returning from `main`).

Comment: Can I assume that it's posix behavior that threads may still run while libc is munmap()'ing shared libs at exit ?